# Javascript, um id que ficou null(vazio) pode ser devolvido?

Tags: javascript, funções, id

Estou precisando saber se é possível devolver um `id` que foi removido, pois quero obter o mesmo e remover o id="", e depois clicar em um `button` por exemplo, para recolocar o que estava antes.

(Objetivo)

1• Clico em button e remove √

2• Clico em outro button e devolve X (já que foi pra null não consigo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você remover o `id` do elemento, não conseguirá recuperá-lo, a não ser que você o guarde em algum lugar, mas isso seria complicado se forem vários elementos.

Você pode usar outros métodos para manter o `id` do elemento caso necessite recuperá-lo futuramente. Um deles é usar *dataset*, criando um atributo `data-id`, ex.:

```
<a id="" data-id="foo" href="">link</a>
```

Ao apagar o `id` do elemento, posso puxar depois pegando pelo *dataset*:

```js
function teste(){
   
   var elemento = document.querySelector("a");
   
   elemento.id = elemento.dataset.id;
   
   //somente para ilustrar
   elemento.innerHTML = "id recuperado!";
}
```

```html
<a id="" data-id="foo" href="">id vazio</a>
<br>
<button onclick="teste()">Recuperar id</button>
```